# Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, derby

I am trying to run SparkSQL :

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

But the error i m getting is below:

```
        ... 125 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /root/spark/bin/metastore_db.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
        ... 122 more
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /root/spark/bin/metastore_db.
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.privGetJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.getJBMSLockOnDB(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data.BaseDataFileFactory.boot(Unknown Source)
```

I see there is a **metastore_db** folder exists..
My hive metastore includes mysql as metastore.But not sure why the error shows as derby execption

Comment: Is your question: "I thought I was using mysql for my metastore_db, but Spark thinks I am using Derby. Why is that?" Or is your question: "I intended to use Derby for my metastore_db, but Spark is failing to open the database because some other Derby application already has the database open. Why is that?"

Comment: No..I dont want to use derby..it takes autometically....not sure why this is error..

Comment: This will help https://dataunbox.com/caused-by-error-xsdb6-another-instance-of-derby-may-have-already-booted-the-database-metastore_db/

Answer (score 37):

I was getting the same error while creating Data frames on Spark Shell :

**Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /metastore_db.**

**Cause:**

I found that this is happening as there were multiple other instances of Spark-Shell already running and holding derby DB already, so when i was starting yet another Spark Shell and creating Data Frame on it using RDD.toDF() it was throwing error:

**Solution:**

I ran the ps command to find other instances of Spark-Shell:

**ps -ef  | grep spark-shell**

and i killed them all using kill command:

**kill -9 Spark-Shell-processID ( example: kill -9 4848)**

**after all the SPark-Shell instances were gone, i started a new SPark SHell and reran my Data frame function and it ran just fine :)**

Comment: Killing hive process and restarting it helped, Thanks!

Comment: ps -ef | grep spark-shell

Comment: This helped me.

Comment: This.  `spark-shell` was running even though I had killed `iTerm2`.  That was an interesting phenomenom.

Answer (score 15):

If you're running in **spark shell**, you shouldn't instantiate a HiveContext, there's one created automatically called `sqlContext` (the name is misleading - if you compiled Spark with Hive, it will be a HiveContext). See similar discussion [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9776).

If you're not running in shell - this exception means you've created more than one HiveContext in the same JVM, which seems to be impossible - you can only create one.

Comment: But if the shell is doing so automatically, how could a user avoid it to work around the issue?

Comment: The user doesn't need to work around it - the cause for the error is the user trying to create _another_ context by calling `new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)` - if you simply avoid doing that, you lose nothing (because you already have a HiveContext you can use) and overcome the error.

Comment: The problem is that it seems to happen automatically with current spark v2.2. Just starting a second spark-shell on the same machine is sufficient to cause the error.

Answer (score 6):

an lck(lock) file is an access control file which locks the database so that only a single user can access or update the database.
The error suggests that there is another instance which is using the same database. Thus you need to delete the .lck files.
In your home directory, go to metastore_db and delete any .lck files.

Comment: With no knowledge of hadoop, I wonder if this question give information enough to be useful. Consider editing it and adding info of what `.lck` files are.

Comment: this worked for me! Was trying to load elastic search

Answer (score 4):

Another case where you can see the same error is a Spark REPL of an AWS Glue dev endpoint, when you are trying to convert a dynamic frame into a dataframe.

There are actually several different exceptions like:

- `pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"`
- `ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /home/glue/metastore_db.`
- `java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader`

The solution is hard to find with google but eventually it is described [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-samples/issues/1).

The loaded REPL contains an instantiated `SparkSession` in a variable `spark` and you just need to stop it before creating a new `SparkContext`:

```
>>> spark.stop()
>>> from pyspark.context import SparkContext
>>> from awsglue.context import GlueContext
>>>
>>> glue_context = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
>>> glue_frame = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database=DB_NAME, table_name=T_NAME)
>>> df = glue_frame.toDF()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing issue during bringing up WAS application on windows machine:

1. kill java processes using task manager
2. delete `db.lck` file present in `WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv04\databases\EJBTimers\server1\EJBTimerDB` (My DB is EJBTimerDB which was causing issue)
3. restart application.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue while creating table.

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE....
```

I could see many entries for `ps -ef | grep spark-shell` so I killed all of them and restarted `spark-shell`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This happened when I was using pyspark ml Word2Vec. I was trying to load previously built model. Trick is, just create empty data frame of pyspark or scala using sqlContext. Following is the python syntax -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

schema = StructType([])`
empty = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)
```

This is a workaround. My problem fixed after using this block. 
Note - It only occurs when you instantiate sqlContext from HiveContext, not SQLContext.

Comment: Wow, that works great for me thanks, I was spending ages trying to load a Pipeline.model from pyspark.ml which I previously saved on another system. Do you know what causes this issue?

(also minor thing: I tried to edit your answer to remove the stray backtick but StackOverflow wouldn't allow me since the edit was less than 6 characters).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error by running `sqlContext._get_hive_ctx()`
This was caused by initially trying to load a pipelined RDD into a dataframe
I got the error
`Exception: ("You must build Spark with Hive. Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true' and run build/sbt assembly", Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.\n', JavaObject id=o29))`
So you could running this before rebuilding it, but FYI I have seen others reporting this did not help them.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error while running test cases in my multi maven spark setup.
I was creating sparkSession in my test classes separately as unit test cases required different spark parameters every time which I am passing it through a configuration file.
To resolve this I followed this approach.
While creating the sparkSession in Spark 2.2.0

```
//This is present in my Parent Trait.
def createSparkSession(master: String, appName: String, configList: List[(String, String)]): SparkSession ={
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAll(configList)
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master(master)
      .config(sparkConf)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .appName(appName)
      .getOrCreate()
    spark
  }
```

In my test classes

```
//metastore_db_test will test class specific folder in my modules.
val metaStoreConfig = List(("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL", "jdbc:derby:;databaseName=hiveMetaStore/metastore_db_test;create=true"))
    val configList = configContent.convertToListFromConfig(sparkConfigValue) ++ metaStoreConfig
    val spark = createSparkSession("local[*]", "testing", configList)
```

And post that in maven clean plugin I am cleaning this hiveMetaStore directory.

```
//Parent POM
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>metastore_db</directory>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>spark-warehouse</directory>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Child Module POM

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>hiveMetaStore</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>spark-warehouse</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: whats is configContent

Comment: is it working fine for multiple test cases  ?  for one or 2 test cases its working fine when I am running multiple suites then I am getting this error

Answer (score -2):

The error came because of the multiple spark shell you are trying to run in same node or due to system failure its shut down without proper exit the spark shell, In any of the reason you just find out the process id and kill them, for that us

```
[hadoop@localhost ~]$ ps -ef | grep spark-shell
hadoop    11121   9197  0 17:54 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto spark-shell
[hadoop@localhost ~]$ kill 9197
```

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party but in your example you just killed the process you used to look for processes. And even that was already gone at the point you used kill.

Answer (score -3):

its very difficult to find where your derby metastore_db is access by another thread, if you are able to find the process then you can kill it using kill command.

Best solutions to restart the system.